# Get property of a class/object dynamically (not knowing the property name beforehand) in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, properties

I want to get a property of an object `$class->property` but I don't know the name of the property I will try to attain.

It might be `$class->property_one` or it might be `class->property_two`.
The information whether it's **one** or **two** is stored in a variable, let's call it `$var`.

The closest I got is this `${'$class->property_'.$var}`but the problem is PHP seems to think I'm looking for a variable called "`$class->property_xxx`", while in fact I want $property from $object.

Thank you for you suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the manual page about [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

You can do it like this:

```
$property = 'property_' . $var;
echo $obj->$property;
```

or with the so called [curly syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) like this:

```
echo $obj->{'property_' . $var};
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I keep this question up or delete it?

Comment: Keep it up. It's a typical question, every PHP has asked himself once a time. And it was upvoted ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj->{'property_' . $var};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$test_class = new stdClass();

$test_class->property_one = 'p_one';
$test_class->property_two = 'p_two';

$var = 'two';

echo $test_class->{"property_$var"};
```

Prints 'p_two'